# Histogram shows unlimited bins despite bin specification in matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-visualization, histogram

I have a error data and when I tried to make a histogram of the data  the intervals or the bin sizes were showing large as shown in the below image

[image]

Below is the code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    
plt.figure()
plt.hist(error)
plt.title('histogram of error')
plt.xlabel('error')
plt.show()
```

When I tried to explicitly mention the bins as we usually do, like in the below code I get the hist plot as shown below

```
plt.figure()
plt.hist(error, bins=[-4,-3,-2,-1, 0,1, 2,3, 4,])
#plt.hist(error, bins = 6)
plt.title('histogram of error')
plt.xlabel('error')
plt.show()
```

[image]

I wish to make the hist look nice, something like below (an example from google) with bins clearly defined.

[image]

i Tried with seaborn *displot* and it gave a nice plot as shown below.

[image]

```
import seaborn as sns

sns.displot(error, bins=[-4,-3,-2,-1, 0,1, 2,3, 4,])
plt.title('histogram of error')
plt.xlabel('error')
plt.show()
```

Why is that the *matplotlib* not able to make this plot? Did I miss anything or do I need to set something in order to make the usual histogram plot? Please highlight

Comment: Try flatten your data, i.e. pass `np.ravel(error)` to `plt.hist()`

Comment: Flattening worked :) Thanks. The error was in numpy array format. Can you please mention how did flatten helped and why didn't the array format worked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The matplotlib documentation for [`plt.hist()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html) explains that the first parameter can either by a 1D array or a sequence of 1D arrays. The latter case is used if you pass in a 2D array and will result in plotting a separate bar with cycling colors for each of the rows.

This is what we see in your example: The X-axis ticks still correspond to the bin-edges that were passed in - but for each bin there are many bars. So, I'm assuming you passed in a multidimensional array.

To fix this, simply flatten your data before passing it to matplotlib, e.g. `plt.hist(np.ravel(error), bins=bins)`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Yes, the data was in 2D numpy array format (surprising to me as well) and when I flattened it like you suggested it worked. This explains why earlier plotting hist took so much time (without flattening) as the library seems to have a hard time in considering every row as a bin. With ravel (flattening) the hist plot was abrupt. Thanks, that solved my query.